# How get global list from a TFS custom widget?

Tags: tfs

I read many guides about developing custom TFS widget (like this one https://blogs.infosupport.com/creating-a-vsts-dashboard-widget) but I din't find a documented way to get items of global list from a widget. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean - do you want to display the global list in a dashboard widget?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to display a global list both from inside a dashboard widget. I'd like to display a global list in the widget wizard (configuration) too.